# How to optimize a JOIN of two tables that require lookups on the column to join on?

Tags: mysql, inner-join, cross-join

I am doing a simple INNER JOIN of two tables with the additional requirement that each table must first be joined with a separate 1:n table to get the correct join values. Illustrating with a simple example, I have three tables **UserInstalls** (UserId, InstallDate), **UserConversion** (UserId, ConversionDate), and **UserAccounts** (UserId, AccountId). I want a final result of (AccountId, InstallDate, ConversionDate).

```
UserInstalls
+--------+-------------+
| UserId | InstallDate |
+--------+-------------+
|      1 | 2015-01-11  |
|      2 | 2015-03-21  |
|      3 | 2015-02-05  |
|      4 | 2014-06-01  |
|      5 | 2014-01-23  |
|      6 | 2015-02-14  |
+--------+-------------+
```

```
UserConversion
+--------+----------------+
| UserId | ConversionDate |
+--------+----------------+
|      7 | 2015-01-15     |
|      8 | 2015-03-03     |
|      9 | 2015-08-01     |
|     10 | 2015-01-02     |
|     11 | 2014-01-24     |
|     12 | 2015-02-17     |
+--------+----------------+
```

```
UserAccounts
+--------+-----------+
| UserId | AccountId |
+--------+-----------+
|      1 |         1 |
|      7 |         1 |
|      2 |         2 |
|      8 |         2 |
|      3 |         3 |
|      9 |         3 |
|      4 |         4 |
|     10 |         4 |
|      5 |         5 |
|     11 |         5 |
|      6 |         6 |
|     12 |         6 |
+--------+-----------+
```

I can simply use subqueries to lookup the AccountID, and then join the results of each subquery. In this trivial case this works fine. In practical applications involving (10,000+ rows), this is not efficient and I run into spool limitations.

```mysql
SELECT x.AccountID, InstallDate, ConversionDate
FROM (SELECT AccountID, InstallDate FROM UserInstalls
    JOIN UserAccounts
    ON UserInstalls.UserId = UserAccounts.UserId) x
JOIN (SELECT AccountID, ConversionDate FROM UserConversion 
    JOIN  UserAccounts
    UserConversion.UserId = UserAccounts.UserId) y
ON x.AccountId = y.AccountId;
```

Any ideas to do this without subqueries or creating multiple tables via a script? Cross-joins? Relational division?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just join the tables together without subqueries:

```mysql
SELECT ua1.AccountID, ui.InstallDate, uc.ConversionDate
FROM UserAccounts ua1
JOIN UserInstalls ui on ua1.UserId = ui.UserId
JOIN UserAccounts ua2 on ua1.AccountID = ua2.AccountID
JOIN UserConversion uc on uc.UserId = ua2.UserId
```

Comment: This does not work and returns 0 rows. The UserIds in UserInstalls and UserConversion are mutually exclusive, therefore there are no rows that meet the conditions of each JOIN.

Comment: I didn't catch that in the original post, I have updated the select with another join on UserAccounts. Let me know if that gets you closer.

Comment: For this particular case, I think this is the best answer. DRapp's answer works too and I'll keep both in my toolbox depending on what the situation calls for. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

You need left-joins but start with the user accounts table as the root...

```
select
      UA.AccountID, 
      MAX( UI.InstallDate ) as AccountInstalled,
      MAX( UC.ConversionDate ) as ConversionDate
   from
      UserAccounts UA
         LEFT JOIN UserInstalls UI
            on UA.UserID = UI.UserID
         LEFT JOIN UserConversion UC
            on UA.UserID = UC.UserID
   group by
      UA.AccountID
```

The group by on account will basically look at the one that qualifies the join from either respective side.  You will now have one row per person and the respective install and conversion date.

Answer (score 0):

please check below query, if don't get required results then create a sqlfiddle so that I can check the issue.

```
SELECT ua1.AccountID, ui.InstallDate, uc.ConversionDate 
FROM UserInstalls  ui
JOIN UserAccounts ua ON ui.UserId=ua.UserId
JOIN UserConversion uc ON ui.UserId=uc.UserId 
JOIN UserAccounts ua1 ON ua.AccountId=ua1.AccountId;
```